# How do I add simple Facebook og tags in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, facebook-opengraph

I cannot believe this question has never been asked and answered before.

How do I add og tags in Meteor for Facebook to read? Just putting it between `<head>` and `</head>` does not work for `og` tags, but it does work for regular meta tags.

And yes, let's say for now I'm perfectly content with doing this statically.

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty straightforward to add Meta tags using [DocHead package](https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/dochead).

If you need them to be static, you can pretty much add the meta tags inside a `Meteor.startup()` method, using Dochead

i.e : In your client-side code, just add the meta tags to your main route, or in a client-side `Meteor.startup()` method.

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
    name: '/',
    action: function () {
          DocHead.setTitle("X");
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'og:image', content: 'image_URL'});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'og:image:width', content: '2083'});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'og:image:height', content: '1091'});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'og:site_name', content: 'X'});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'og:title', content: X});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'og:type', content: 'website'});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'og:description', content: 'X'});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'og:keywords', content: 'X'});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'fb:app_id', content: 'X'});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'description', content: 'X'});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'keywords', content: 'X'});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'twitter:card', content: 'summary'});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'twitter:url', content: 'X'});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'twitter:title', content: 'X')});
    DocHead.addMeta({property: 'twitter:description', content: 'X'});
        BlazeLayout.render('appLayout', {
            top: '_header',
            main: 'home'
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT : SSR is not the only way FB crawlers can see your meta tags, using [prerender](https://juststartworking.com/meteor-and-seo-the-right-way/) works as a charm too, and would require less work in this case

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 3):

From Meteor 1.3 you can use `dynamicHead` hooks with a server side router, for example :

```
Picker.route('/', (params, req, res, next) => {
    req.dynamicHead = (req.dynamicHead || "") + '<meta name="metaname1" content="metacontent1">';
    req.dynamicHead += '<meta name="og:title" content="mytitle">';
    next();
});
```

This adds two meta tags to initial html head so there would be no problem in crawlers. By using this method the only package you need is a server side router which in the above example I've used [Picker](https://github.com/meteorhacks/picker).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Blaze, you can use [meteorhacks/meteor-ssr](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr) and [meteorhacks/picker](https://github.com/meteorhacks/picker). They will work also for dynamic content.

You can follow this guide on how to use these two packages to solve your problem: [Meteor Server-Side Rendering for SEO Purposes](https://meteorhacks.com/meteor-server-sider-rendering-for-seo-purpose/)

Comment: I don't want to make a HUGE change to my site (probably a full week of workload and hiring a sysadmin) just because of adding a simple tag that might as well be static. Also, the whole point of Meteor is rendering on the client so... no thanks.

Comment: Well good luck then... simply put, Facebook crawlers do not run JS, so there is no way they can see your open graph tags

Comment: How come other crawlers that do not run JS can see meta tags? Like a simple meta tag analyzer on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has no point to use ssr in a meteor app, you lose lots of the benefits that meteor gives you, and using prerender.io can be expensive if you have a web page with many url's also since meteor 1.4 the library fast-render stops working in ssr, so it's painful to make it work from my own experience.
A solution might be to create another service in your server that create the meta tags for fb, for example, you give to Facebook the URL http://my server.com:8080/id-of-your-post, this would be a ssr service that check on your database all the stuff to generate the tags and send them in the HTML file.
It's time for Facebook to do like google and index JavaScript based sites. Technology is changing, but they are not.